# Преобразование угла и расстояния в координаты

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, любой-язык, формулы

Есть два числа - угол (0-360) и дистанция.

Их нужно преобразовать в координаты xy при условии что начальная точка - (0;0)

Какой формулой нужно вычислять x и у?

Просьба при возможности (и желании) объяснить почему так работает

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82

Comment: Интересно, какой юности участники у нас появились? Насколько я помню, у моего малого это было классе в 9...

Comment: ну я в восьмой закончил так что...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот в такой системе координат
[image: Схема]

x = r*cos(φ)
y = r*sin(φ)

Для справки:

[image: тригонометрические функции]